# pass the selected value of a @Html.DropDownListFor to a @switch in view

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

Net Core and have run into a speed bump. I desire to get the selected value of a @Html.DropDownListFor and pass the string value to a switch to continue to display the rest of my form.

I seen numerous ways to @onchange on stack but no way to pass the variable's data to a @switch
Model

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    // New guild yes or no
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Are you registering a NEW GUILD?")]
    public string RegisterNewGuild { get; set; }
    // If yes      
    [Display(Name ="Are you the Guild Leader of the guild your are trying to register?")]
    public string GuildLeader { get; set; }
    //if yes
    [Display(Name = "As the Guild Leader, What is your character's name?")]
    public string GuildLeaderName { get; set; }
    // if NOT THE guild leader  and register new guild was marked yes.
    [Display(Name = "As the Guild Member who is registering your guild, what is your Guild Leader's character name?")]
    public string GuildLeaderNameViaMember { get; set; } 
    // get the persons character name who is registering
    [Display(Name = "What is your character's name?")]
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = " What is your Guild's name?")]
    public string GuildName { get; set; }
}
public enum GuildLeaderEnum
{
    Yes,
    No
}
public enum RegisterNewGuildEnum
{
    Yes,
    No
}
public enum GuildNameEnum
{
    Test1,
    Test2
}
```

View

```html
@model RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewData["Title"].</h2>

<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
     <div id="RegisterNewGuild" class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="RegisterNewGuild" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RegisterNewGuild,
                    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(RegisterNewGuildEnum))),
                    "")
           </div>
    </div>
  
    @switch ()// This is where i need help to Capture the string from the select list above)
    {
        case "Yes":

                    <div id="GuildLeader" class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="GuildLeader" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">

                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GuildLeader,
                    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(GuildLeaderEnum))),
                    "")
                           

                        </div>
                    </div>
            switch ()// This is where i need help to Capture the string from the select list above)
            {
                case "Yes":
        <div id="GuildLeaderName" class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="GuildLeaderName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input asp-for="GuildLeaderName" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                    break;
                case "No":
                    <div id="GuildLeaderNameViaMember" class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="GuildLeaderNameViaMember" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input asp-for="GuildLeaderNameViaMember" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    break;

            }

            break;
        case "No":
            <div id="MemberName" class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MemberName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input asp-for="MemberName" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>


            <div id="GuildName" class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="GuildName" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GuildName,
                    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(GuildNameEnum))),
                    "")
                   

                </div>
            </div>
            break;


    }
```

Controller

```
 // GET: /Account/Register
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Register( string returnUrl = null)
    {



        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null )
    {

        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
                // Send an email with this link
                //var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                //var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
                //await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Confirm your account",
                //    $"Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");

              return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);


            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Just check the Model property if it's already set? If not, the drop down is rendered on client-side so you would need to do this with JavaScript.

Comment: Tried '
            <select asp-enum-for="RegisterNewGuild" onchange="GetSelectedTextValue(this)"></select>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetSelectedTextValue(RegisterNewGuild) {
            var selectedText = RegisterNewGuild.options[RegisterNewGuild.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
        }
    </script>

  
    @switch (selectedText)'

Comment: But the javascript variable selectedText is not available to the @switch()